# Nextjs weather app trying to call api. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I get unauthorized error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, async-await, fetch-api, openweathermap

Am I doing the api handling right? Or is there something I'm missing? This was originally a create react app project and now I'm trying to migrate to nextjs so maybe I'm missing something with how api calls should be done. Let me know if I need to show any more of my code.

This is in a separate from the main program.

```
export default async function ApiHandler(location) {
  
  try{
       

    const data = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&units=imperial&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`
      );
  
    const res = await data.json();

    
    console.log(res.data);
    
      } catch (error){
          console.log("Error connecting to api");
          return new Response("Error in getting weather data", { status: 500 });
      }

}
```

Comment: Migrating from CRA to nextjs most likely has nothing to do with anything. But lack of error message and link to api documentation in your post is making  it hard to help you

Comment: Given the information provided my bet would be that `process.env.API_KEY` is not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NextJs you need to use the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix on your env variable for them to be exposed in client components (assuming you are using a client component here)

See the docs:

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Comment: This worked thank you. I apparently did not name the env local file correctly either so those two changes made it all work. Thank  you again.